# How to select the results based on different conditions involving multiple dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table with items similar to the following which contains item names, SoldDate (if sold) and DisplayInWebsiteDate (this is date upto which that item should be displayed in website if not sold)

```
Id      ItemName      IsSold       SoldDate        DisplayInWebsiteDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         Shirt         0            NULL              2020-03-28
2         Pant          1          2019-10-20          2020-04-25
3         Jacket        1          2020-01-05          2020-01-20
4         Trouser       0            NULL              2020-01-10
```

I want to **SELECT** the items based on the following conditions:

```
1. If item is not Sold i.e SoldDate is NULL then check if its DisplayInWebsiteDate is 
   greater than current date and that would be valid

2. If item is Sold i.e SoldDate has some date then ignore DisplayInWebsiteDate and check if that item was 
   sold within last 30 days, and display. If it was sold more than 30 days earlier, then don't get that record
```

**Today's date is 2020-01-22 Therefore, the result would be following**

```
1. Shirt is VALID because it is not sold, and DisplayInWebsiteDate is greater than today's date
2. Pant is INVALID because it is sold, so we ignore its DisplayInWebsiteDate. 
   And its sold date has passed more than 30 days form today's date
3. Jacket is VALID because it was sold just 17 days ago i.e it falls within range of 30 days sold date
4. Trouser is INVALID because it is not sold and its DisplayInWebsiteDate has already passed on January 10, 2020
```

**Expected Result:**

```
 Id      ItemName      IsSold       SoldDate        DisplayInWebsiteDate
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         Shirt         0            NULL              2020-03-28
 3         Jacket        1          2020-01-05          2020-01-20
```

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh I have updated the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty simple via the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  ID int,
  ItemName nvarchar(100),
  IsSold int,
  SoldDate datetime,
  DisplayInWebsiteDate datetime
)

INSERT INTO t VALUES
(1, 'Shirt', 0, NULL, '2020-03-28')
,(2, 'Pant', 1, '2019-10-20', '2020-04-25')
,(3, 'Jacket', 1, '2020-01-05', '2020-01-20')
,(4, 'Trouser', 0, NULL, '2020-01-10');


SELECT *
  FROM t
  WHERE (SoldDate IS NULL AND DisplayInWebsiteDate > GETDATE())
    OR (SoldDate IS NOT NULL AND DateDiff(d, SoldDate, GETDATE()) <= 30)
```

However, you could parametrize the Days and so on... but basically I think that's it.

See SQL Fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36538/4/1

Answer (score 1):

Using an `OR` for both conditions should do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE (
    (SoldDate IS NULL AND DisplayInWebsiteDate > CAST(GetDate() AS DATE))
    OR 
    (SoldDate >= DATEADD(day,-30, CAST(GetDate() AS DATE)))
)
```

Comment: @Vim You're welcome. :) Btw, if it's a big table and there's an index on SoldDate then this alternative should prove to be the fastest.  If there's no index on solddate then it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
SELECT [Id], [ItemName],  [IsSold], [SoldDate], [DisplayInWebsiteDate]
FROM tbl
WHERE ([ISSOLD] <> 1 AND (CAST([DisplayInWebsiteDate] as date) >= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
       OR
       ([ISSOLD] = 1 AND DATEDIFF(day, [SoldDate], CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) <= 30))
```

SQL Fiddler is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39e6d/5/0)

Comment: No, it doesn't work because it is checking DisplayInWebsiteDate with today's date for all items and therefore doesn't satisfy the condition number 2 i have mentioned

Comment: @Vim Please check. Updated my answer and added fiddler too.